# How to get user's presence using Slack API?

Tags: slack-api

I need to monitor presence of users across many difference channels.

There are thousands of users across all of those channels.

- https://api.slack.com/methods/users.getPresence does not have any way to batch requests.
- https://api.slack.com/events/presence_query is not available to modern scoped apps.
- There is no `presence_*` event.

How does one track which users are present?

Comment: Have you checked out the access log method? It will give you login info for all users per call (with paging). Requires you to be on a paid plan though: https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs

Comment: Requires `admin` permission though. No one is going to grant that for a 3rd party app.

Comment: OK, I thought that was for your own workspace. Then you only other option is `users.getPresence` and live with the rate limit.